# Creating a function, accidentally overwriting the output

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am new to R so this is probably quite simple, but I am having an issue with the function I wrote- I need it to return an updated dataframe but it's returning the original.

I've created a function in R where the input is an 1) empty dataframe, `signal` (with two columns, `times` and `import`, 2)  a vector of days treatment is implemented (so for example, 30, 60, 90 means treatment was given on those days) and a 3) `model_fit`, which brings in the curve that shows how treatment wears off over time. The output is the new dataframe that uses the vector of treatment days to bring in the data from `model_fit` into the signal$import column and the corresponding times.

I tested out each line of my code for my function and they work- my issue is I can't figure out how to properly return the updated dataframe.  Here's my code:

```
#Initial vectors for days post treatment, % killed
x <- c(4, 30, 60, 90, 120, 210, 360) #days post treatment
z <- c(1.0, 0.99, 0.99, 0.79, 0.7, 0.02, 0) #% killed

#create model fit:
fit2 <- nls(z ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), data = data.frame(x, z))
summary(fit2)

lines(seq(0, 400, length.out = 400),
      predict(fit2, newdata = data.frame(x = seq(0.5, 400, length.out = 400))))

# Create function:
trt.function <- function(model_fit, vector_of_trt_days, signal) {
  #inputs
  times <- seq(0, 20000, by = 1)
  signal <- data.frame(times = times, import = rep(0, length(times)))
  Asym<-summary(fit2)$parameters[1,1]
  xmid<-summary(fit2)$parameters[2,1]
  scal<-summary(fit2)$parameters[3,1]
  trt.start = vector_of_trt_days
  trt.end = c(trt.start + 400)
  trt.segments <- unlist(Map(':', trt.start, trt.end))
  time.segments <- rep(0:401, times=length(trt.start))
  signal$import[trt.segments] = (Asym / (1 + exp((xmid - times[time.segments] / scal))))
  return(signal)
}
```

This code keeps giving me an empty dataframe back.  I'm know the code works when not in a function- the last line then returns the correct output.  I tried using `return(signal$import[trt.segments] = (Asym / (1 + exp((xmid - times[time.segments] / scal))))` but it gave me an error due to the =.

Can someone let me know how to return the new updated dataframe?  I keep accidentally returning the original one.  Thanks!

Just for reference, this code gives me the correct return outside the function:

```
#Create empty dataframe
times <- seq(0, 20000, by = 1)
signal <- data.frame(times = times, import = rep(0, length(times)))

# inputs
Asym<-summary(fit2)$parameters[1,1]
xmid<-summary(fit2)$parameters[2,1]
scal<-summary(fit2)$parameters[3,1]

trt.start <- c(10000,10090,10180,10270)  #input for start times of treatments 
trt.end <- c(trt.start + 400) #input for the end times of treatments
trt.segments <- unlist(Map(':', trt.start, trt.end)) #Create the treatment segments
time.segments <- rep(0:401, times=length(trt.start)) #create the corresponding time segments 

signal$import[trt.segments] = (Asym / (1 + exp((xmid - times[time.segments]) / scal)))
```

Comment: What are `signal` and `vector-of_trt_days` passed into the function?  In the last line of code, you are indexing `times` where the index is starting from 0.  In `R`, indexing starts from 1

Comment: If I use `out <- trt.function(fit2, c(30, 60, 90), signal = NULL)` it is not. showing any error as. `signal` is created inside the function

Comment: An example of what I'm trying to pass would be this: `trt.days =   c(10000,10090,10180,10270) #Vector of treatment days
trt.function(fit2, trt.days, signal)`

Comment: I am not getting any error with that as well, I useed `signal = NULL`

Comment: Your code you helped me with yesterday gave the correct dataframe- I just added an edit so you can see what gives me the proper output outside the function.  I'm just having trouble figuring out if the issue is that by using `return(signal)' I am just returning the original empty df accidentally, or if there is another issue

Comment: With your function, I get `out <- trt.function(fit2, trt.days, signal)#
 dim(out)#
[1] 20001     2`

Comment: When I was googling, I came upon other examples where the issue was that a dataframe was creating inside a function.  Is there a way to then apply this function given a dataframe, vector of days, and inputting the `model_fit`?

Comment: I was confused that within your function the `signal` is getting afresh instead of the one that is passed as input.  So you don't need the `signal` argument

Comment: For some reason, when I plot it without using the function (with the code I put at the bottom of my post I get the correct plot, but when I use the function, the plot isn't correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you clarify which signal argument I don't need?

Comment: I would say, try on a smaller subset to track the issue instead of a larger sample as

Comment: I meant inside the function, the 3rd line is creating the `signal` `signal <- data.frame(times = times, import = rep(0, length(times)))`. So, why do you need to pass `signal` as argument to function

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Thanks, the main issue was that I completely forgot to do what you showed with `out <-trt.function(fit2, trt.days, signal)`.  I can move on to figuring out why the plots arent correct now.  Thank you!